# How to create a optimization where for value of x I get y such that y is minimum and x is maximum

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming

```
X= [23, 174, 3, 38, 22, 97, 11, 5, 36, 94, 25]
y = [8, 58, 2, 13, 8, 86, 5, 2, 23, 60, 20]
```

Now using linear regression I got coefficient = 0.46
y intercept 4
Now I need to find the optimum proportion of y and x

I am not sure if linear regression can be of help. is there any optimization process that can take all this into consideration or the coefficient itself gives that value

Comment: This might be more appropriate for https://stats.stackexchange.com or https://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Sourav Roy, Can you explain a bit more in details what do you mean by "value of x I get y such that y is minimum"? When you fit your data with linear regression you can predict value of y given x, after that what you suppose to do? I could not get it clearly?

Answer (score 0):

This will make a dictionary out of your lists with `x` as keys and `y` as values. You can now access the dictionary with your `x` value and get the appropriate `y` value.

```py
min_max_values = dict(zip(x, y))
for k, v in min_max:
    print ("min: {min}, max: {max}".format(min=v, max=k)
```

```
Output:
min: 8, max: 23
min: 58, max: 174
...
```

Comment: I believe it will be         min_max_values = dict(zip(x, y))
                                    for k, v in min_max_value:
                                         print (("min: {min}, max: {max}".format(min=v, max=k))

Comment: I need a optimum value based on the trend of x . If i give x = 45 what is the best y i can get based on the matrix

Comment: For those questions it would really be better if you ask them in other places like the links provided by @AMC.